# midi input in python

Tags: python, file, midi

I'm coding a demo in python and I need to read a MIDI file in python (no real-time stuff is needed).
In particular, I'm looking for a library which preserves channel information.

The most promising libraries I found are:

- http://code.google.com/p/midiutil/
- http://www.mxm.dk/products/public/pythonmidi

Any experience with those?

Thanks a lot

Nicola Montecchio

Answer (score 2):

I've been using MXM's library in [harpy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/harpy/) for some time now, and am quite satisfied with it. Fast enough for my purposes, and easy to extend. I suppose it does what you need, seeing as how I use it to split MIDI files into single channel files.